# Extract common values from Spring OAuth2 YML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have following .yml file with OAuth2 configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          evesso:
            client-id: xxxxxx
            client-secret: yyyyyy
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
          evessostats:
            client-id: xxxxxx
            client-secret: yyyyyy
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1,esi-clones.read_implants.v1,esi-skills.read_skills.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
          evessofc:
            client-id: xxxxxx
            client-secret: yyyyyy
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1,esi-clones.read_implants.v1,esi-skills.read_skills.v1,esi-fleets.read_fleet.v1,esi-fleets.write_fleet.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
        provider:
          evesso:
            authorization-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/verify
            user-name-attribute: CharacterName
          evessostats:
            authorization-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/verify
            user-name-attribute: CharacterName
          evessofc:
            authorization-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/verify
            user-name-attribute: CharacterName
```

And as you can see there is way too much of redundant data. Is there any way to trim it down?

Comment: Programmatically, yes, but do you want it to stay in the properties file?

Comment: @TwiN preferably, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's impossible to significantly reduce the size of your `.yml` or `.properties` configuration without using code.

However, you can still significantly improve your configuration by grouping duplicate key strings.

E.g.

```
server:
  port: 8080
  url: http://localhost:${server.port}

oauth2-redirect-url: ${url}/login/oauth2/code/
oauth2-client-id: xxxxxx
oauth2-client-secret: yyyyyy

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          evesso:
            client-id: ${oauth2-client-id}
            client-secret: ${oauth2-client-secret}
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: ${oauth2-redirect-url}
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
          evessostats:
            client-id: ${oauth2-client-id}
            client-secret: ${oauth2-client-secret}
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: ${oauth2-redirect-url}
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1,esi-clones.read_implants.v1,esi-skills.read_skills.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
          evessofc:
            client-id: ${oauth2-client-id}
            client-secret: ${oauth2-client-secret}
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            response_type: code
            redirectUriTemplate: ${oauth2-redirect-url}
            scope: esi-location.read_location.v1,esi-clones.read_implants.v1,esi-skills.read_skills.v1,esi-fleets.read_fleet.v1,esi-fleets.write_fleet.v1
            clientName: EVE SSO
```

While this doesn't save lines, but instead add extra lines, it is significantly cleaner. If you have to change the port, then you only have to change `server.port` instead of changing every single `redirectUriTemplate`.

***NOTE**: I only showed the result on some of the fields, but you can apply it for every values that have duplicated strings (e.g. scope, provider uri, etc.) .*

You can also split your configuration into different files (e.g. all oauth2 config could be in `application-oauth.yml`) and then include that file by using `spring.profiles.active`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: oauth2
```

But even if you do that, I still recommend that you also use the first suggestion I made above, as that will minimize the duplicated values to the bare minimum.